# Simple Android Timer Game

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer

I know there are a few Android Timer posts, and I can't really see what I'm missing from them.

The user presses a button to begin the game, text is updated with the seconds that have passed, and, if the button is pressed after eight seconds, a congratulatory message is displayed.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public static long startTime;
    public static int time;
    public static boolean buttonClicked1;
    public static boolean buttonClicked2;
    public static boolean win;
    public static TextView todd;
    public static TextView tim;
    public static Button bob;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        win = false;
        bob = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        tim = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.message);

        todd = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.timer);
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        time = 0;
        buttonClicked1 = false;
        buttonClicked2 = false;

        bob.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(!buttonClicked1){
                    buttonClicked1 = true;
                    bob.setText("Push Here");
                    play();
                }
                else if(buttonClicked1) //Has game started
                {
                    if(time>8)
                        buttonClicked2 = true;

                }                   
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    public void play(){
        playThread paul = new playThread();
        paul.run();
    }

    public void winner(){
         tim.setText("Congratulations");
    }

    public boolean checkWin(){
        return buttonClicked2 ? true : false;
    }

    public void updateTime(){
        if((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) % 1000 > 0){
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            time++;
        }
        todd.setText(""+time);
    }

    private class playThread implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            System.out.println("Thread running");
            while(!win){
                updateTime();
                win = checkWin();
                winner();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I decided to implement Runnable instead of extending Thread for the playThread private class after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread).

The game becomes unresponsive after hitting the start button, the text of which doesn't change to "Push Here".

I am, of course, a complete Android beginner, and I suspect the issue is with my implementation of a thread, but the problem may be elsewhere because I'm not too familiar with the programming style or conventions.

Thanks for looking this over!

Answer (score 0):

Your `playThread` class, despite its name, does not create a new thread. It runs in the main GUI thread and contains a loop that hangs your app. Creating an instance of this class a calling its run method simply runs that code in the main thread. You should create a thread an run that instance in that separate thread.

Comment: If he starts the thread on an actual seperate thread, he will get a `CalledFromWrongThreadException` in `winner()`.

Comment: I thought the Runnable class, like a thread, ran separately, and would not cause the app to hang. How can I repeatedly update the time without a loop?

Comment: `Thread thread = new Thread(new playThread()); thread.start();` starts the Runnable on a seperate thread

Comment: @Nick Runnable it an interface that you can pass to a Thread instance, which would run its `run` method in a new Thread when that thread is started.

Comment: I'd help more, but I ran into issues with this approach and drew out the timer onto the canvas of a SurfaceView directly rather than mess around with TextViews. As I said, even if you start the thread, the `winner()` will access the TextView from another Thread, and not the UI thread (this results in an `CalledFromWrongThreadException `). You can of course call `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { winner(); });` but there's definitely a better approach than that, hence why I abandoned the text view for display in a use-case like this. (I was writing a game)

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm trying the edits. I added some background about my original understanding of Runnable to the main post.

Comment: @Nick, Just to underscore what Eran already said, there is nothing magic about Runanble.  It is _just_ an interface.  A Runnable object is an object with a run() method.  What you do with it is up to you.  What some Thread object, t, does with it is, it calls the run() method in the new thread _after_ somebody creates the new thread by calling t.start().

Comment: I fiddled with the code and moved winner() out of the thread and to the button onClickListener, where I relocated checkWin(). The only thing left in the playThread is "while(!win){updateTime()}". The only result seems to be that the button now changes to the text "Push Here" moments before crashing.